# There is nothing here worth {for} dying for

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction

I found this phrase in a sign`There is nothing here worth dying for` and I don't understand why the `for` is at the end of the phrase and not after `worth`. I tried to search in English and I found it's perfectly normal finish a sentence with a preposition, but it didn't explain anything more.

Answer (score 2):

The patterns are:

- be worth + Noun / V-ing
- to die for (some goal), e.g. *die for your country*
- to die of (a disease), e.g. *die of a heart attack*
- to die from the injuries you sustained in an accident

"There is nothing here worth dying for" means: "There is nothing **for which** it is worth dying" ("for" introduces a relative clause specifing the cause one would be ready to die for -- in this case, none). Notice, then, that "for which" attaches to "dying", not to "be worth".

In everyday English, we prefer to place the preposition at the end and to avoid placing it at the beginning of a relative clause, where it sounds too formal.